# imdecode returning None when using urllib

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to read an img from a url. My code works when the img is coded jpeg, but, when It's .svg for example, the function imdecode from openCV just don't work. Here it is the code:

```
url_response = urllib.urlopen("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/BanderaEstepa.svg")
img_array = array(bytearray(url_response.read()), dtype=uint8)
img_url = cv2.imdecode(img_array, 1)
```

Need help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read docs: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#Mat imread(const String& filename, int flags)

Comment: No support for `.svg`

Comment: So do you think there is a way to convert .svg to .jpg without having to download the file of the URL or something like this? Thanks for your help!